# php mysql - select most recent data from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have searched this site and others but cannot find any help with this problem. Maybe I am making this more difficult than necessary.

I have two tables as follows. I want to return all the information for each item but only the most recent data and include data from both tables

table 1: serviceRequestSubmission

**sid        customerID**
1001     11111
1002     22222
1003     33333
1004     44444
1005     55555

table 2: serviceRequestHistory

**historyID      requestID      statusUpdate**
1                  1001               Assigned
2                  1002               Assigned
3                  1003               Pending
4                  1004               Delayed
5                  1002               Pending
6                  1002               Closed

I want to return:

**sidID            historyID      statusUpdate**
1001            1                   Assigned
1002            6                   Closed 
1003            3                   Pending 
1004            4                   Delayed 
1005            -                    Submitted

I have tried the following code but it returns all the rows of data but I only want the most recent/highest historyID.

```
SELECT serviceRequestSubmissions.*, serviceRequestHistory.* 
FROM serviceRequestSubmissions 
LEFT JOIN serviceRequestHistory ON serviceRequestSubmissions.sid = serviceRequestHistory.requestID 
ORDER BY serviceRequestSubmissions.sid DESC
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: Why dont put it in one table?

Comment: You can just Limit it for as much as you want or add time stamp and create new statement

Comment: @Jonasw  a concept known as "normalization" / the "relational" in relational database

Comment: You can use `TIMESTAMP` in your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT serviceRequestSubmissions.*, serviceRequestHistory.* 
FROM serviceRequestSubmissions 
LEFT JOIN serviceRequestHistory 
    ON serviceRequestSubmissions.sid = serviceRequestHistory.requestID
    AND historyID IN (
        SELECT max(historyID) 
        FROM serviceRequestHistory
        GROUP BY requestID
    )
ORDER BY serviceRequestSubmissions.sid DESC
```

**EDIT:**

Only closed:

```
SELECT serviceRequestSubmissions.*, serviceRequestHistory.* 
FROM serviceRequestSubmissions 
JOIN serviceRequestHistory 
    ON serviceRequestSubmissions.sid = serviceRequestHistory.requestID
    AND historyID IN (
        SELECT max(historyID) 
        FROM serviceRequestHistory
        WHERE statusUpdate = 'Closed'
        GROUP BY requestID
    )
ORDER BY serviceRequestSubmissions.sid DESC
```

Comment: This worked!  I tried max(historyID) but not in this way. Merci MNV.

Comment: If I want to return a list of closed items, do you think it it best to check for the status inside the subquery or outside with another subquery?  My concern is as the db grows too many subqueries may slow down the request.

Comment: At this case you must add condition into subquery. And it is good at this case because result of subquery will be more short.

Comment: You mean something like this........  SELECT serviceRequestSubmissions.*, serviceRequestHistory.* 
FROM serviceRequestSubmissions 
LEFT JOIN serviceRequestHistory 
    ON serviceRequestSubmissions.sid = serviceRequestHistory.requestID
    AND historyID IN (
        SELECT max(historyID) 
        FROM serviceRequestHistory WHERE statusUpdate = 'Closed'
        GROUP BY requestID
    )
ORDER BY serviceRequestSubmissions.sid DESC

Comment: I updated answer. "A shorter query?" No. More short result of subquery. Less data rows - more performance.

Comment: What I posted above to get the closed status does not seem to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: It returns all rows, even those that do not have closed status.

Comment: Updated answer. Replace `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`

Comment: This worked but if I change the status of the closed request back to open, it still shows as closed. Seems it is not getting the max(historyID) any more. Any other suggestions?  Thanks so much for your time and help.

Comment: It is other problem of `serviceRequestHistory` table. You can improve your code for adding duplicate values into `serviceRequestHistory` when request backed to one of previous states.

Comment: I have added a mainStatus column in the serviceRequestSubmissions table and will update it with each change of status. That should take care of it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Add a LIMIT clause at the end of the query:

`LIMIT 2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TIMESTAMP` or `id` in your database and fetch record which has greatest `TIMESTAMP` or `id` value or with descending `TIMESTAMP` or `id` order by `LIMIT` clause

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem of type  `greatest-n-per-group`. I think this is the best way to solve it:

```
SELECT
    s.sid sidID,
    IFNULL(h1.historyID,'-') historyID,
    IFNULL(h1.statusUpdate,'Submitted') statusUpdate
FROM
    serviceRequestSubmissions s
    LEFT JOIN serviceRequestHistory h1 ON ( s.sid = h1.requestID )
    LEFT JOIN serviceRequestHistory h2 ON ( s.sid = h2.requestID AND ( h1.historyID < h2.historyID OR h1.historyID = h2.historyID AND h1.requestID < h2.requestID ) )
WHERE
    h2.requestID IS NULL
ORDER BY
    s.sid
```

This is how it works: given a row of the table `serviceRequestHistory`, there shouldn't be any other row with the same `requestID` and a greater `historyID` (the conditions after the `OR` is to solve the ties). This kind of solution is usually better than using sub-selects.

Comment: We have differing definitions of "best". This kind of solution is cute, but it's NEVER better than a 'sub-select' (specifically an uncorellated sub-select)