# MySQL- Find the most recent data from 5 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 5 tables, which have data as follows

**Table 1**

```
id_1     name          created_at                        flag
=============================================================
1        Daniel        2021-03-16 12:25:18                0
2        Pearson       2021-03-18 10:25:10                0
3        Scottie        2021-03-19 12:25:18               0
4        Mike           2021-03-21  13:40:03              0
```

**Table 2**

```
id_2     name            created_at                    flag
==============================================================
1        Louis           2021-03-11  10:25:10            0
2        Jessica         2021-03-12  11:36:16             0
3        Maggie         2021-03-21   12:25:18             0
4        Megan            2021-03-13 13:40:03             0
```

**Table 3**

```
id_3     name            created_at                      flag
==================================================================
1        Jon               2021-03-10 12:16:45             0
2       Natalie            2021-03-08 12:45:15             0
3       Victoria           2021-03-08 12:51:00             0
4        Michael           2021-02-12 12:51:17             0
```

**Table 4**

```
id_4      name            created_at                      flag
==============================================================
1        Emily           2021-03-11 13:14:23                0
2        Rose             2021-03-11 12:14:20               0
3       Abigaile           2021-03-11 15:28:56              0
4       Mac               2021-03-11 13:14:23               0
```

**Table 5**

```
id_5      name            created_at                        flag
==================================================================
1        Abella            2021-03-12 12:51:17               0
2        Patrick            2021-03-12 11:48:17              0
3        Josh               2021-03-12 10:52:17              0
4        Goldwin            2021-03-12 13:24:17              0
```

*I want to get the **most recent** data, and the **most outdated** data.*

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047818/php-mysql-select-most-recent-data-from-two-tables) answers mostly the same, based on *two* tables. But what if there are 5 (as is my case), or even more. Should I use `join` or is there anything better?

P.S- Also ,there may be tens of thousands of data from each table to search for.

Comment: What do you want to return?  The time of the most recent and oldest entry, or the entire row?  i.e. what is your expected resultset from running this query on your example data?

Comment: @JeffUK Most recent and most outdated Row.

Comment: Dare we ask why you have several apparently identical tables

Comment: @Strawberry They are different. I am too lazy and busy to write that down

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it would be best to perform a **Union** between the identical tables as a subquery, then perform ordering operations and potentially limits on the result. You can flip the **ORDER BY** (**DESC**/**ASC**) for the two different queries.

```
SELECT name,
       created_at
FROM   (SELECT name,
               created_at
        FROM   table1
        UNION
        SELECT name,
               created_at
        FROM   table2) t
ORDER  BY created_at DESC
LIMIT  5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want for the most recent data?
For the most outdated, you just change `ORDER BY` from `DESC` to `ASC`.

```sql
SELECT t.name, t.created_at
FROM   
   (
       (SELECT name, created_at FROM table1 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5)
       UNION
       (SELECT name, created_at FROM table2 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5)
       UNION
       (SELECT name, created_at FROM table3 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5)
       UNION
       (SELECT name, created_at FROM table4 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5)
       UNION
       (SELECT name, created_at FROM table5 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5)
   ) AS t
ORDER  BY t.created_at DESC
LIMIT  5;
```